# Plasma 5: add new Device Notifier actions

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, kde, panel, plasma-5

The Device Notifier is the KDE/Plasma 5 panel applet that offers a list of actions for removable devices like dvds.

How to edit that list?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Device/Solid Actions**

KDE System Settings > Removable Storage > Device Actions

or

System Settings > Device Actions (under 'Hardware')

or

search "solid" or "device actions" in KRunner (Alt-Space) or any application launcher and select Device Actions.

KDE online Device Actions Handbook: https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kde-workspace/kcontrol/solid-actions/index.html

> This module allows you to set up the actions you want to associate
>   when you plug new devices.

Comment: In 16.04 with Plasma 5.6.5 that setting is not *KDE System Settings > Removable Storage > Device Actions* and is not mentioned in the posted link. (It's  simply *System Settings > Device Actions*).